# Magento 2.4.4 - Products backend keyword search is very slow

Tags: magento2.4.4

Magento 2.4.4, new installed, on ubuntu 22.04, php8.1, nginx, varnish, redis, elasticsearch, with sample data.
On the backend - catalog->products -> search by keywords, search is to slow, up to 5 Minutes. Everything - on the backend and frontend - is very fast.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution.
Problem was in the database server version. First i installed mariadb. By default, ubuntu 22.04 will install the version 10.6.7. And here is the problem. With mariadb versions 10.3, 10.4, 10.5 or with mysql 8 everything works fine. Only the newest versions of mariadb cause problems.
I uninstalled mariadb and installed mysql 8. And now it work fine for me.

Comment: Would you like to improve the processing speed of your MySQL 8 installation?

Comment: @WilsonHauck how? do you have tips?

Comment: Yes at www.mysqlservertuning.com

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu and Magento performance is based on your system, the higher the processor and ram and higher the performance, if you have too many projects in one system, it also slows down system performance