# Setup:upgrade is extremely slow on magento 2.4.4

Tags: magento2.4.4

Following are my system configurations

- OS : Ubuntu 20.04
- Server : Nginx
- RAM : 16 GB
- SSD Hard disk

Setup:upgrade used to run faster before the fresh OS installation. I ran into some problem so re-installed the OS and now it is working slow. Even the OS seems to be booting slow.
I'm not sure if the issue is with OS or magento related applications.

I don't have much products, hardly 20 products. Basically I don't have much data so data  could not be the problem.

Please suggest the possible solutions or a way to debug the root cause for this. Thanks

Comment: This might help you - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/355822/77554

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
# cores on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Additional OS information request, please. 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: I figured out the problem. The OS and all the softwares were installed in HDD disk instead of SSD. I had 2 drives in my system. When I reinstalled the OS  and all the softwares to SSD, I got a good speed there.